# Как реализовать генерацию размещений без повторений?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Как лучше реализовать функцию `permutate` с сигнатурой (JavaScript)

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // множество элементов
const k = 2; // размер размещений

const permutations = permutate(array, k);
```

где `permutations` — все [**размещения**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) из *array* по *k* (все возможные *k*-элементные **упорядоченные** подмножества без повторений из *array*)?

---

Пример ожидаемого возвращённого значения:

```js
const permutations = [
    ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'a']
];
```

Comment: в математику вдаваться не охото может не заумными словами опишешь функцию и результат а я попробую все это дело перенести в js

Comment: @Armen В общем случае поиск всех "размещений" это т.н. "брутфорс", но в данном случае речь о его подвиде, когда элементы исходного набора не могут повторяться. В вышеприведённом случае ответом должен быть следующий набор размещений: `[1, 2, 3]`, `[2, 3, 1]`, `[3, 1, 2]`, `[1, 3, 2]`, `[2, 1, 3]`, `[3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: понятно а К за что отвечает?

Comment: наверное количество вариантов? но оно уже в функции должен вычисляться как аргумент передавать не правильно. Попробую реализовать кину ответ

Comment: @Armen *k* это размер размещений, т.е. при `k = 3` нужно перебрать размещения из трёх элементов (`[1, 2, 3]`, <...>), а при `k = 2` — из двух (`[1, 2]`, <...>).

Comment: @Armen Количество вариантов вычисляется по классической формуле:  
`A^k_n = !n / (n - k)!`; меня же интересует сам набор размещений, представленный в виде **массива**.

Comment: На других языках, не на JS - устроит?

Comment: @MBo Ну если есть с этим проблемы, то можно.

Comment: @Артём Ионаш Ответ не помог? Питоновский или дельфийский варианты, наверное, нетрудно в JS переделать.

Comment: @MBo Ответ помог, просто сигнатура-то отличается немного. Хотя по сути это решение, конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на **JavaScript**:

```js
// const permutate = <T>(arr: T[], k: number, withRepetition = false) => {
const permutate = (arr, k, withRepetition = false) => {
  const permutations = [] // T[][]
  const permutation = Array(k) // T[]

  // const internalPermutate = (elements: T[], depth: number): void => {
  const internalPermutate = (elements, depth) => {
    if (depth === k) {
      permutations.push([...permutation])
      return
    }
    elements.forEach((element, index) => {
      permutation[depth] = element
      const partial = withRepetition
        ? elements
        : [...elements.slice(0, index), ...elements.slice(index + 1)]
      internalPermutate(partial, depth + 1)
    })
  }
  internalPermutate(arr, 0)
  return permutations
}


const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const k = 2

const permutations = permutate(array, k)
console.log({ permutations : permutations.map(p => p.join()) })
```

*Примечание: решение на основе автоподсказок GitHub Copilot.*

Answer (score 4):

Delphi (не требует передачи текущего состояния):

```
procedure Arrangement(var A: array of Integer; n, k: Integer; s: string);
  var
    i, t: Integer;
  begin
    if k = 0 then
      Output(s)
    else
      for i := 0 to n - 1 do begin
        t := A[i];
        A[i] := A[n - 1];  //store used item in the tail
        Arrangement(A, n - 1, k - 1, s + IntToStr(t) + ' ');  //recursion without tail
        A[i] := t;  //get it back
      end;
  end;
```

C++ (153 соответствует 1,5,3)

```
void GenArrangement(int n, int k, int idx, int used, int arran) {
    if (idx == k) {
        std::cout << arran << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        if (0 == (used & (1 << i))) 
            GenArrangement(n, k, idx + 1, used | (1 << i), arran * 10 + (i + 1));
}

int main()
{
    GenArrangement(5, 3, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Python

```
def genArr(n, k, ar, used, idx):
    for i in range(n):
        if not i in used:
            used.add(i)
            ar[idx] = i
            if idx == k - 1:
                print(ar) #comment for large n
            else:
                genArr(n, k, ar, used, idx + 1)
            used.remove(i)

n = 5
k = 3
genArr(n, k, [0]*k, set(), 0)
```

Comment: MBo - ты просто кросавчег!

Comment: самому не смог сделать но вот реализации правда на ES5 синтексисе но вроде то что надо https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Armen Это тоже не то

Comment: @MBo я здаюсь))